# How to add a Form (or Dialog) in C++ 14 Native DLL (not clr) - VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I developed a DLL using Native API technology in pure C++ 11. And now I want to show a Form or a Dialog to the user before calling a certain function whicj will contains some Authorization License Input Fileds (for example - user and password).

Is it really possible to do it somehow, without connecting runtime and clr?
I already google it and found that I need add New Resource and choose there Dialog. And after that I need to call this Dialog.

I need exactly call and show Form only from my DLL (without using any dependencies).
Please dont suggest C# or .NET external variants.

This is my Visual C++ VS 2019 DLL Project config: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBRmX.jpg

Comment: Yes it's possible Search the Windows API for DialogBox, DialogBoxIndirect, CreateDialog, and/or CreateDialogBoxIndirect. Your program will require a message pump of some form if you go the modeless dialog route. And if all of that sounds Greek to you (no offense to the Greeks), you probably need some time with a formal basic winapi book (Petzold's is still the classic reference, but MS' online docs have really come a long way).

Comment: There must be several tens of thousands of examples and tutorials on how to do this all over the Internet. What have you searched for? What have you found? What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I haven't found any "tens and thousands" of tutorials on this topic. As I wrote above - I found only one single tutorial on how to add a Resource with the "Dialogue" type. All other tutorials were devoted to creating a C ++ / CLI DLL or creating Forms in C #. All this does not suit me, since my code is "unmanageable", as far as I understand correctly.

Give examples where you found "thousands" of tutorials, I'll laugh. And if I found the answer, I would not ask the question here.

Comment: `DialogBox, DialogBoxIndirect, CreateDialog, and CreateDialogBoxIndirect` could do it. I suggest that you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [Using Dialog Boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes).